# Programmatically delete images from WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, image, media, attachment

I need to programmatically delete images from the **WordPress Media Library**. But, I'm at a loss as to how to do this.

To clarify: I need to be able to add code to my theme functions file or a custom plugin that will allow me to use the **WordPress API / hooks** to remove an image by the **ID assigned to it by WordPress**.

Comment: Is it really 'self explanatory' ? Eitherway, if you want people to help you figure out an issue, you should provide as much info as possible. Otherwise,  its a bit rude expected people to work out what you mean, what you want to do, AND then expect them to give you part or all of the answer. Give it a try and you might get some traction going.

Comment: I'm wanting to know what the PHP code would look like or what it would be to delete an image (by the image ID appointed to it by the WordPress media library uploader). 

That's what i was meaning by "Pretty self explanatory". I was speaking in regards to my own question, not the expected answer.

Comment: If I had any code examples or anything i have tried thus far I would have provided them. I have looked to no avail, so sorry for the lack thereof.

Comment: I was aware of that! However the point still remains. Set out your objectives, and the where and the whens. That way people can help you. I suspect this is quite an easy thing to resolve but without having anything like the necessary detail it's a shot in the dark for anyone prepare to try and answer it. Update your question with the scenario at hand, and I or someone else will probably be able to help in a matter of minutes.

Comment: Eg: I need to do A when B  because C. So far I have tried X and Y but not sure how. Is it possible to do something like Z. (p.s. Im just trying to help you get a solution).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here try this:

```
<?php wp_delete_attachment( $attachmentid, $force_delete ); ?>
```

or if you want to just send the image to the trash:

```
<?php wp_delete_attachment( $attachmentid ); ?>
```

WordPress Codex has more details: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_attachment

Comment: That's it. Just stumbled upon it myself but thank you.